# Cannot find the SQL Server binary in Docker Container

Tags: sql-server, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a custom image for SQL Server and need to apply some initialization scripts and data migrations before the application connects to it.
So I searched for this in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-configure?view=sql-server-ver16&pivots=cs1-powershell#customcontainer) but I am facing a weird problem, where my `entrypoint.sh` file is not able to find the `sqlservr` binary. This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

USER root
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the entrypoint.sh and migrations.sh files for running all the required migrations 
COPY . .

# Setup the environment for the mssql container
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=testPass#1234
ENV MSSQL_PID=Developer

# Expose the port 1433 for other services 
EXPOSE 1433

# Make both the files executable
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh 
RUN chmod +x ./migrations.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr

# CMD "/bin/bash"
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "./entrypoint.sh"]
```

This is my `entrypoint.sh` file

```bash
echo "********************************* Started SQL Server Image *********************************"
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

This is my docker run output

```bash
[+] Building 0.2s (11/11) FINISHED                                                                                                                                           docker:default
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 618B                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [1/6] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 97B                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [3/6] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [4/6] RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [5/6] RUN chmod +x ./migrations.sh                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [6/6] RUN chmod +x /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:a9ff35832dec4ba79f8ca2d36580ddef2d13d221f646068eaa896dc2d165b921                                                                                           0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/todo-db                                                                                                                                             0.0s
database-test
********************************* Started SQL Server Image *********************************
: No such file or directorypt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

Comment: Among other things you should include `USER mssql` before your entrypoint. The SQL Server process is meant to run as a least-privilege user, not root.

Comment: Have you double-checked the contents of your `entrypoint.sh` file? (And the version inside your custom image?) The error message suggests there are some control characters at the beginning of the `/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr` line.

Comment: The specific way the error message is presented suggests to me that the script has DOS line endings, so it's trying to run a binary named `sqlservr\r` ending with a carriage return character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments the problem was in the file endings being CRLF instead of LF. Posting this answer for anyone who stumbles upon the same problem.

Updated Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

USER root
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install dos2unix functionality for converting CRLF file endings to LF
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y dos2unix && \
    apt-get clean

# Copy the entrypoint.sh and migrations.sh files for running all the required migrations 
COPY . .

# Setup the environment for the mssql container
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=testPass#1234
ENV MSSQL_PID=Developer

# Expose the port 1433 for other services 
EXPOSE 1433

# Convert all the file endings
RUN dos2unix ./entrypoint.sh
RUN dos2unix ./migrations.sh

# Make both the files executable
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh 
RUN chmod +x ./migrations.sh

USER mssql

CMD ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```